# Regarding ratings of hotel

Tags: hotels, booking.com, google-search

Different websites give different ratings for the same hotel. Why is it like that? Which one is the correct one?

For example:

Senani Hotel in Kandy: Google shows it to be a 2 star hotel

But booking.com at the following link

https://www.booking.com/hotel/lk/senani.en-gb.html?aid=357026;label=gog235jc-hotel-XX-lk-senani-unspec-in-com-L%3Aen-O%3AwindowsS81-B%3Achrome-N%3AXX-S%3Abo-U%3AXX-H%3As;sid=83cff77d63c2ae40aeb0264a6357d90b;dist=0&keep_landing=1&sb_price_type=total&type=total&  shows it to be a 4 star.

Which is the correct rating?

Comment: I’d go with the Google rating https://support.google.com/business/answer/7660515?hl=en-GB as they seem to use more reliable criteria https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/news/2017/08/bookingcom-offered-the-same-hotel-as-both-a-three-and-four-star-offer/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Difficult to be sure but IMHO 4 stars seems unlikely to be accurate if comparing worldwide. There appears to be no universal standard for hotel ratings https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel_rating The higher star ratings typically indicate greater luxury, a wider range of facilities, and good/excellent overall guest services. On Booking.com for countries where there’s no official system it seems that stars are ‘self-selected by properties during the sign-up process’ https://www.which.co.uk/reviews/uk-hotel-chains/article/hotel-star-ratings-explained Sri Lanka appears to classify properties by type rather than by star http://www.sltda.lk/classification_of_tourist_hotels therefore it’s impossible to say whether a 2 star or 4 star rating is ‘’correct’.

Answer (score 0):

There's no common standard being established internationally on the hotel star's rating.

Each country establishes its own star rating process and implemented it through associations or through government departments.

Having said that, the star ratings still serve as a good guideline for one to choose a hotel.

In your case, I believe the star rated reported on Google was submitted by the hotel through Google Business listing.

On top of star rating, I would suggest to check out third-party review sites. E.g.
[TrustPilot](https://www.trustpilot.com/)

Comment: The assertion that "Each country establishes its own star rating process" is incorrect. Governments do not always set such standards. Many ratings are created by hotel chains, or travel agents, or other private or commercial enterprises.

Comment: And there may be no star rating at all, or just one the hotel decides for themselves based on whatever criteria they want. If ratings are done by private companies (such as AAA's diamond ratings in North America), hotels may choose not to participate if they don't want to pay for it or don't think they'll like the results.